# svgpanzoom: beforeZoom on return false doesn't halt

Tags: javascript, svgpanzoom

I am using this awesome plugin. But have a problem with zoom halt

```
        panZoom = svgPanZoom('#svg3336', {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            controlIconsEnabled: false,
            fit: true,
            center: true,
            panEnabled: true,
            zoomScaleSensitivity: 2,
            beforeZoom: function(){

                if(zoomed)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    zoomed = true;
                }
            },
            mouseWheelZoomEnabled: false,
            minZoom: 0.1
        });
```

so on `return false` my map disappear. I have check matrix data and I see there is a big minus on coordinates

```
transform="matrix(5.630453109741211,0,0,5.630453109741211,-2396.02587890625,-7678.998046875)"
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you zoom using mousescroll it is done relatively to the point of mouse pointer position. Thus you don't just scroll, you also pan.

In your example only prevents zooming but panning is still working when scrolling using mousescroll.

A solution would be to also cancel panning if it is right after zooming:

```
beforeZoom: function(){
  isZooming = true;
  if(zoomed) {
    return false;
  } else {
    zoomed = true;
  }
},
beforePan: function(){
  if(isZooming) {
    isZooming = false;
    return false;
  }
}
```